# Using strtok/strtok_r with multiple strings in a char pointer array

Tags: c

I am somehow new to programming and have a problem with the following task. The programm should read names (userinput stdin) until EOF (CTRL+D) line by line. The names can have multiple blanks inbetween. After that, the programm should sort the names depening on command line arguments:

- no argument: ascending (works)
- -d: descending (works)
- -n "number": take the n'th word of each name and sort by that name (for normal names it would be the last name) -> not working

My problem is, that I am not sure how to use **strtok** with multiple strings. I read, that when using **strtok** with multiple strings I will run into problems, so I should go for **strtok_r**. But I can't figure out how to use it in my case properly.

**strtok** will go through the string until it reaches the delimiter (in my case space) and can store the string after that in another string for example. But with **strtok_r** I really don't understand how to use that properly in my case.

Any suggestions/hints? I think I am just too blind to see the light at the end of the tunnel :)

Thank you in advance!

```
    #define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 500
    #define MAX_LINES 1000

    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    //void swapAscending(char **)

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        char            *names [MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
        char            tempNameHolder[500];
        char            *tempSortNameHolder;
        char            *tempSortNameHolderNthA;
        char            *tempSortNameHolderNthB;
        char            delimiter[]         = " ";
        char            *strPtrA;
        //char          *strPtrB;

        int             writeIndex          = 0;
        int             sortIndex           = 0;
        int             elementCounter      = 0;
        int             compareReturnBSAsc  = 0;
        int             compareReturnBSDsc  = 0;
        long            convertedValue      = 0;
        unsigned long   stringLengthBSAsc   = 0;
        unsigned long   stringLengthBSDsc   = 0;

        unsigned long   currentStringLength = 0;

        //Convert argv[argc-1] to int

        convertedValue = strtol(argv[argc-1], NULL, 10);

        printf("Enter the name: ");

        while (fgets(tempNameHolder, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin))
        {
            currentStringLength = strlen(tempNameHolder)+1;

            names[writeIndex] = malloc(currentStringLength);

            strcpy(names[writeIndex], tempNameHolder);

            elementCounter++;

            printf("Enter the name: ");

            writeIndex++;
        };

        //strPtrA = strtok(*(names), delimiter);
        strPtrA = strtok_r(*(names), delimiter, names);
        //strPtrB = strtok(*(names + sortIndex), delimiter);


        //Sort ASCENDING without argument

        if (argc == 1)
        {
            for (int currentIndexA = elementCounter; currentIndexA > 0; currentIndexA--)
            {
                for (int currentIndexB = 0; currentIndexB < currentIndexA -1; currentIndexB++)
                {
                    compareReturnBSAsc = strcmp(*(names+currentIndexB), *(names+currentIndexB+1));

                    if (compareReturnBSAsc > 0)
                    {
                        tempSortNameHolder = *(names + currentIndexB);
                        *(names + currentIndexB) = *(names + currentIndexB+1);
                        *(names + currentIndexB+1) = tempSortNameHolder;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else if ((argc == 2) && (strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0))
        {
            //Sort DESCENDING without argument

            for (int currentIndexA = elementCounter; currentIndexA > 0; currentIndexA--)
            {
                for (int currentIndexB = 0; currentIndexB < currentIndexA -1; currentIndexB++)
                {
                    compareReturnBSDsc = strcmp(*(names+currentIndexB), *(names+currentIndexB+1));

                    if (compareReturnBSDsc < 0)
                    {
                        tempSortNameHolder = *(names + currentIndexB);
                        *(names + currentIndexB) = *(names + currentIndexB+1);
                        *(names + currentIndexB+1) = tempSortNameHolder;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else if ((strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[2], "-n") == 0))
        {
            //Sort ASCENDING with n-th word

            for (int currentIndexA = elementCounter; currentIndexA > 0; currentIndexA--)
            {
                for (int currentIndexB = 0; currentIndexB < currentIndexA -1; currentIndexB++)
                {
                    for(int currentIndexC = 0; currentIndexC < 2; currentIndexC++)
                    {
                        strPtrA = strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &names[currentIndexB]);
                    }

                    tempSortNameHolderNthA = strPtrA;
                    /*
                    for (int currentIndexD = 0; currentIndexD < 2; currentIndexD++)
                    {
                        strPtrB = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
                    }

                    tempSortNameHolderNthB = strPtrB;
                     */
                    sortIndex++;

                    compareReturnBSAsc = strcmp(tempSortNameHolderNthA, tempSortNameHolderNthB);

                    if (compareReturnBSAsc > 0)
                    {
                        tempSortNameHolder = *(names + currentIndexB);
                        *(names + currentIndexB) = *(names + currentIndexB+1);
                        *(names + currentIndexB+1) = tempSortNameHolder;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        printf("\n");

        for (int currentIndexC = 0; currentIndexC < elementCounter; currentIndexC++)
        {
            printf("%s", *(names+currentIndexC));
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If your question is about how to use [`strtok_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) correctly, then you could remove almost *all* of the rest of the code you have. Please spend some time to learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `strtok_r` is used just like `strtok`, except that you need to supply a pointer to a `char *` variable which you have defined somewhere, one for each string you want to tokenize. You can call them `tokenstate1` and `tokenstate2` if you want. You don't need to initialize them nor read their value.

Comment: Okay I guess I’ll try that, thank you ! :)

Comment: This doesn't technically answer your question, but you might want to consider using strsep instead of strtok (which Brian Kernighan described as being the "worst designed function in computing history".